# How to import scss files and use them globally in a React application?

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I have my React application structures like this:

```
-src
|-components
 |-Card.js
 |-Card.scss
 |-Navbar.js
 |-Navbar.scss
|-styles
 |-_mixins.scss
 |-_variables.scss
|-App.js
|-App.scss
```

I use `node-sass` so for component-x I just need to `import component-x.scss` to apply the scss file. However I have the `_mixins.scss` and `_variables.scss` which I need to use on everywhere, I cannot `import` them in each `scss` file. How can I import these files globally so I could use them anywhere I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `main.scss` and import all inside!

There is an example with your files:

```
/********************************SASS MAIN***********************************/
//COMPONENTS
@import "components/card";
@import "components/navbar";

//STYLES
@import "styles/mixins";
@import "styles/variables";
```

Then in your App.js just `import 'main.scss'`

more info about import in sass [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Comment: Just tried it but still failed. In `Card.scss` I had `@import "../styles/_mixins.scss"` which worked. When trying your solution I removed this line and the mixins could not be found.

Comment: name Card and Navbar as _card and _navbar and dont remove the underline of the others.  more info here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: I only want `mixins` and `variables` to be imported globally, but `Card.scss` and `navbar.scss` should still keep as they are.

Comment: Okay, I tweaked a bit and put `_mixins.scss` and `_variables.scss` in `main.scss` in `src` folder, and imported `main.scss` in the component and it worked. However on top of every component which I want to use these global scss variables, I still need to write `@import "./main.scss"`, which is not very handy but better than importing every scss file in `styles` folder

Comment: Mmm that's weird, if you import in you App component you wouldn't need to import anything inside because you actually have it in the mains css that SASS generate.

Comment: I tried again like you said: in `App.js` add `import './main.scss';` after `import './App.scss'`, then tried to use a variable in `Navbar.scss`, got the error: `undefined variable: "$primary"`.

Comment: I recommend that you make a scss file with all the variables. like _mixins.scss but _variables.scss try it

Answer (score 0):

you can use `customize-cra` with `react-app-rewired` and in you  `config-overrides.js`

```
const { override, adjustStyleLoaders } = require("customize-cra");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = override(
  adjustStyleLoaders((loader) => {
    loader.use[1].options.additionalData = `@import "./src/assets/scss/_variables.scss";`;
  })
);
```

and change your package.json scripts into

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```